# where can I store images that will be used in an email?

Tags: image-display

I manage a sharepoint which has a document library which is attached/associated with a workflow. When an item in the document library changes, an email goes out to certain users. That email contains images which are hosted on the sharepoint. The problem is, if the user is not authenticated into the sharepoint (if they are logged out) they will be unable to see the images in their email. Is there anyway I can store the images, such that they will be visible in all emails (even if the user is not authenticated into the Sharepoint)? I tried putting the images in "site assets" but when I manage permissions, there is no way (that I can see) to allow all users "read access" to the assets. As far as site permissions are concerned, I can only "grant" rights to authenticated users (there is no 'group' for unauthenticated users).

Answer (score 0):

we can do it 2 different ways
1. Upload this image in layout folder
2. Upload this image in sharepoint image library and enable annonimous access to this library

But in both case the user and server should have network connection

Comment: where is the layout folder (how do I get there in SP2010)? I dont have access to the central administration (that is handled at a higher level within our enterprise).